# Debugging the C crash dump on Windows x64

Tags: c, debugging, dump, crash-dumps

There is a crash dump (FULL dump created by setting LocalDump registry key as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) that got created on a Windows x64 2008 R2 machine and I am able to debug this dump file using VS 2010 on the same machine (can load symbols for my modules, see modules, function names in stack trace, see code after selecting source files) but when I copy this dump, necessary EXEs, DLLS and their PDBs and the source files to a different Windows x64 2008 R2  machine the VS 2010 can not see the module names and function names in the Call Stack window(can load symbols for my modules though). I am wondering what step I am missing here. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are the same exe and the corresponding pdb used which caused the crash? I mean you can't recompile the same code and use the pdb and exe. You need to have the exe which caused the crash and its corresponding pdb

Comment: Yes, all the binaries and their corresponding PDBs are same on both machines. Another observation made is that when I try to debug the same dump file on Windows x64 2003 machine, the call stack would not even any entries except 2 or 3 entries.

Comment: Sorry, I am not an Windows expert, whatever I suspected I pointed out. Maybe some else would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windbg from the Debugging Tools for Windows. Use the [!sym noisy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command in Windbg to show detailed information about the exe and dll images. This will show you where it can't find the correct pdbs and highlight cases where the pdb doesn't match.  Also check that you have the same symbol paths set up on both machines.